How Should I Organize My Spring Boot File Structure?
I am creating a Film Review app, I created a database schema of my app so far.
Film App Schema
I am not sure how I should organize my project structure. If I have a typical package by layer, then I will have many Java files for each package, and it might look confusing.
I was thinking about packaging by feature, for instance a Person/ folder and a Film/ folder, but I wouldn't know how some entities could fit, "CrewOf.java" would go under the Person folder or the Film folder.

the answer to your question is very subjective, but I would package it by feature.
It will be easier to find classes related to certain functionality, which also makes relocating certain classes related to a functionality easier, instead of going hunting in several packages to find classes related to that functionality, you will find them all under one package.
Also, take a look at the video below, it describes different approaches.
check this video
